# Apply transformations to shapes on canvas on button click-HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to apply transformations to shapes drawn based on the mouse coordinates. I need to make the user enter a value for x and y and then apply transformations according to these values. My ideal flow of event would be the user clicks on a scale button for example, then the user is prompted to enter the value for x and y. Then the shape appears on the canvas based on the transformation.

Here's my complete set of codes:

transform.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
         <title>Drawing Application</title>
         <link href="transform.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1"></canvas>
    <span style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; margin-left:830px; margin-top:280px; background-color:white; font-size:12px;">(0,0)</span>
    <br><output id="out"></output>
    <script src="transform.js"></script>
    <div id="shapeProperties">
    <p>
    <label>
    <div id="shape">
    <p><b>Fill shapes option:</b> <input type="checkbox" id="fillType"></b><br/>
    <p><b><center><u>Shapes</u></center></b>&nbsp; &nbsp;

    <p>Polygon&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="polyBox"><br/>

    </div>

    <div id="color">
    <b><p><center><u>Color Properties</u></center></b><br/>
    <p>Fill Color&nbsp;<input type="color" id="fillColor" value="#000000"/><br/>
    <p>Stroke Color&nbsp; <input type="color" id="strokeColor" value="#000000"/><br/>
    </div>
    <div id="range">
    <b><p><center><u>Other Properties</u></center></b><br/>
    <label>Polygon Sides&nbsp; <input type="range" id="polygonSide" step="1" min="3" max="9" value="3"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="clear">
    <p> <center><input id="clearCanvas" type="button" value="CLEAR"></center></p>
    </div>
    </label>
    </p>
    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

transform.js:

```
var canvas,context,dragging = false ,dragStartLocation,snapshot,shapeBox,fillColor,lineWidth,strokeColor,canvasColor,clearCanvas, transX, transY;

function getMouseCoordinate(event)
{
    var x = event.clientX - myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect().left - transX,
        y = event.clientY - myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect().top - transY;

        return {x: x, y: y}; //return objects
}

function getSnapshot()
{
    snapshot = context.getImageData(0,0,myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height); //get the image while dragging
}

function restoreSnapshot()
{
    context.putImageData(snapshot, 0 , 0); //put the image into the canvas at the same position
}

    function drawPolygon(position, sides, angle) {
        var coordinates = [],
            radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((dragStartLocation.x - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((dragStartLocation.y - position.y), 2)),
            index = 0;

        for (index = 0; index < sides; index++) {
            coordinates.push({x: dragStartLocation.x + radius * Math.cos(angle), y: dragStartLocation.y - radius * Math.sin(angle)});
            angle += (2 * Math.PI) / sides;
        }

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
        for (index = 1; index < sides; index++) {
            context.lineTo(coordinates[index].x, coordinates[index].y);
        }

        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        context.strokeStyle = strokeColor.value;
    }

function changeBackgroundColor() 
{
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle = document.getElementById("backgroundColor").value;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
    context.restore();
}


function canvasClear()
{
    context.clearRect(0,0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
}

function startDrag(event)
{
    dragging = true; //dragging has started
    dragStartLocation = getMouseCoordinate(event);
    getSnapshot();
}

function drag(event)
{
    var position;
    if(dragging  == true) {
        polygonSides = document.getElementById("polygonSide").value;
         restoreSnapshot();
         position = getMouseCoordinate(event); //check whether dragging has started

         if(fillType.checked)
         {
             context.fillStyle = fillColor.value;
             context.fill();
             context.globalAlpha = 0.9;
         }

         if(polyBox.checked)
         {
             drawPolygon(position, polygonSides, 0 * (Math.PI / 180));
         }

    }
}

function stopDrag(event)
{
    polygonSides = document.getElementById("polygonSide").value;
    dragging = false; //stop dragging
    var position = getMouseCoordinate(event);
    restoreSnapshot();


         if(fillType.checked)
         {
             context.fillStyle = fillColor.value;
             context.fill();
             context.globalAlpha = 0.9;
         }

         if(polyBox.checked)
         {
             drawPolygon(position, polygonSides, 0 * (Math.PI / 180));
         }
}

function changeFillStyle()
{
    context.fillStyle=this.value;
    event.stopPropagation();
}
function changeLineWidth()
{
    context.lineWidth=this.value;
    event.stopPropagation();
}


function initiate()
{
    fillColor=document.getElementById('fillColor');
    strokeColor=document.getElementById('strokeColor');

    clearCanvas = document.getElementById('clearCanvas');


    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    transX = canvas.width * 0.5;
    transY = canvas.height * 0.5;

    context.translate(transX, transY);

    context.fillRect(0, -transY, 1, canvas.height);
    context.fillRect(-transX, 0, canvas.width, 1);


    context.strokeStyle = strokeColor.value;
    context.fillStyle = fillColor.value;

    context.lineCap = "round";

    window.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag, false);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);
    fillColor.addEventListener("input",changeFillStyle,false);

    clear.addEventListener("click", canvasClear, false);

}

window.addEventListener('load', initiate, false);
```

This is how the app looks like:

[image]

Can you give me suggestions about how i can prompt the user for the value of x and y or create a text field and have the user input the values and retrieve them using javascript?
I've tried it but i can't get the function to work correctly. Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JS native promt to get the user to input your values - the downside : it can only process one input at once so the user would have to answer multiple promts.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

Demo

```js
var x = prompt("Please enter x", "");
if (x != null) {
    alert("x =  " + x);
}

var y = prompt("Please enter y", "");
if (y != null) {
    alert("y =  " + y);
}
```

A more elegant is a custom promt. There are a lot of examples for this, [here's one from jQueryUI.](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: Can you include it in my code to see how it works? I've tried all sorts of things but the problem is that i can't include it in my codes. I tried with prompts too but i need to get the position of the last drawn shape which forces me to use the drawPolygon function. Can you show me a workable solution please?

Comment: I would consider it if you provide a working live example. I can recommend following sites for setting up such an example : http://www.liveweave.com/,  http://codepen.io/ or http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

I tried, but I couldn't get your example code to run :-(

I offer this alternative as a learning or starting point:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

$sides=$('#sides');
$sides.attr({min:3,max:8}).val(3);
$sides.on('input change',function(){ draw(); });

$radius=$('#radius');
$radius.attr({min:10,max:100}).val(30);
$radius.on('input change',function(){ draw(); });

$fill=$('#fillHue');
$fill.attr({min:-1,max:361}).val(0);
$fill.on('input change',function(){ draw(); });

$stroke=$('#strokeHue');
$stroke.attr({min:-1,max:361}).val(0);
$stroke.on('input change',function(){ draw(); });

$cx=$('#cx');
$cx.attr({min:0,max:cw}).val(cw/2);
$cx.on('input change',function(){ draw(); });

$cy=$('#cy');
$cy.attr({min:0,max:ch}).val(ch/2);
$cy.on('input change',function(){ draw(); });

draw();

function draw(){
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    var sides=parseInt($sides.val());
    var radius=parseInt($radius.val());
    var fill=getColor(parseInt($fill.val()));
    var stroke=getColor(parseInt($stroke.val()));
    var cx=parseInt($cx.val());
    var cy=parseInt($cy.val());

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo (radius*Math.cos(0),radius*Math.sin(0));          
    for (var i=1; i<=sides;i++){
        ctx.lineTo(
            radius*Math.cos(i*PI2/sides),
            radius*Math.sin(i*PI2/sides)
        );
    }
    ctx.fillStyle=fill;
    ctx.strokeStyle=stroke;
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

function getColor(hue){
    if(hue==-1){return('black');}
    if(hue==361){return('white');}
    return('hsl('+hue+', 100%, 50%)');
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#properties{padding:10px; width:200px; display:inline-block; border:1px solid blue;}
input[type=range]{width:175px; padding:0px; margin:0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=properties>
  Polygon sides:&nbsp
  <br>
  <input id=sides type=range>
  <br>
  Polygon radius:&nbsp
  <br>
  <input id=radius type=range>
  <br>
  Fill hue color:&nbsp
  <br>
  <input id=fillHue type=range>
  <br>
  Stroke hue color:&nbsp
  <br>
  <input id=strokeHue type=range>
  <br>
  X:&nbsp
  <br>
  <input id=cx type=range>
  <br>
  Y:&nbsp
  <br>
  <input id=cy type=range>
  <br>
  <button id=add>Add</button>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```